# How to use a field value in Template.php

Tags: nodes, entities, theming

Im sure this is an easy question, just not for me because of lack of experience with the Drupal preprocess hooks. I am removing the standard "Read More" links from my content. I want the ability to replace them with a css button. I can do that, the tricky part come when I want to use a FIELD from the CONTENT TYPE, as the name for the button.

```
function bootstrap_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

 unset($variables['content']['links']['node']['#links']['node-readmore']);

   $variables['newreadmore'] = t('<span class="newreadmore"> <a href="!title" class="btn       
  btn-info" >'.$readmoretext.'</a> </span>',
   array(
    '!title' => $variables['node_url'],
  )
);
}
```

My question is how can i HOOK into the node and retrieve the field for my variable $readmoretext

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the node object in `$variables['node']`, and from there you can use the [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) function to extract your field value:

```
$node = $variables['node'];

// field_get_items() always returns an array, even if the field is limited to one value
$field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');

// Get the value from the first item in the array (if that's the one you need)
$title = $field_items[0]['value'];
```

Comment: This is easiest explanation I have seen on how to do this. Very nice to reference this to refresh my memory when needed. (like today!)