# how to reference a field in a field collection in a page.tpl file

Tags: theming, entities

I have added a field to the basic page content type (a field collection field, to be exact). I want to be able to pull out the content of each field and display it in different format. How can I do this? Which variable contains this data? I am using an override of page.tpl.php.

EDIT: 
I did try dpm($node) and I see the field collection field. However this is the structure I see -

```
field_call_to_action['und'][0]['value']
```

which is equal to 231. I still don't see the actual values of the fields in the field collection.

Comment: entity_load('field_collection_item', array($node->field_collection_name['und']['0']['value']));

Answer (score 2):

You may use `entity_load`. I have a project in which I use Field Collections as you, and this is a fragment of code in my module. I hope it helps you.
The key is the use of **entity_load**.

```
    foreach($node->field_imagenes["und"] as $value){
                $a = entity_load('field_collection_item',     array($value["value"]));
                $prefered = false;
                if(isset($a[$value["value"]]->field_prefered_image["und"][0]["value"]) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Few of the tutorials that may be helpful for you:

- How to print fields in the template file:
  https://drupal.org/node/950434
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681780/drupal-7-access-custom-node-field-in-page-tpl-php
  https://drupal.org/node/1323842
  http://pixeljets.com/blog/writing-robust-code-uses-fields-drupal-7
  [How to use a field value in Template.php](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28280/how-to-use-a-field-value-in-template-php)
- Theme field collection fields:
  https://drupal.org/node/1155752
- Template file suggestion:
  https://drupal.org/node/1089656